# Unable to set the absolute position of modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, position, reveal.js

I have a jQuery modal window that appears upon click of a button. I have a  on the close-modal box where I want to capture the editable text of the modal window upon closing and so I want to make the modal full screen so the user cannot simply click on the main page thus rendering the action on the click of the close modal defunct.

I have tried setting the position as absolute with top:0 left:0 bottom:0 right:0 as mentioned on some posts but this is not working. The modal is being displayed relative to the position of the click despite setting the values in line so I am unsure as to why this is happening. It keeps adding random values to the top style despite being specified.

Is there anyway round this?

Comment: you have set position:absolute ?

Comment: yes position absolute is set

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to put the div of the modal window right after de  tag? And try to aadd body, html {width:100%; height 100%; }

Comment: I am not fully sure what you mean but yes the width and height are set to 100%